# How do I create a single stream from a vector of Files?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to read multiple files and I'd like to create a stream from a vector of filepaths. I've been fighting with the compiler for some time and I'm not sure how to make this work:

```rust
fn formatted_tags_stream(
    args: &[&str],
    files: &Vec<PathBuf>,
) -> Result<impl Iterator<Item = String>> {
    
    // Transform list of paths into a list of files
    let files: Vec<File> = files.into_iter().map(|f| File::open(f)).flatten().collect();

    // Here is where I'm stuck :/
    let stream =
        files
            .into_iter()
            .skip(1)
            .fold(BufReader::new(files[0]), |acc, mut f| acc.chain(f));

    Ok(BufReader::new(stream).lines().filter_map(|line| {
        line.ok().and_then(|tag| {
            if let Ok(tag) = serde_json::from_str::<TagInfo>(&tag) {
                Some(tag.format())
            } else {
                None
            }
        })
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `fold`, the function must always return the same type. However, if you'd use it as you write, the function would take a type `F` and return a `Chain<F, ...>` in the first pass. The next pass would need to take a `Chain<F, ...>` and return a `Chain<Chain<F, ...>, ...>` - leading to "different types per iteration". This would not work as Rust wants to know the exact type, and the type has to stay the same.

However, you could type-erase the thing and hide it behind a pointer (i.e. a `Box`, doint "trait objects"). See [here (I did some minor adjustments to make it compile)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=52cd09919d301a8a156c9dbbae4f4ac6):

```
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::BufRead;

fn formatted_tags_stream(
    args: &[&str],
    files: &Vec<PathBuf>,
) -> Result<impl Iterator<Item = String>, ()> {
    
    // Transform list of paths into a list of files
    let files: Vec<File> = files.into_iter().map(|f| File::open(f)).flatten().collect();

    // Here is where I'm stuck :/
    let bufreader = Box::new(std::io::empty()) as Box<dyn Read>;
    let stream =
        files
            .into_iter()
            .fold(bufreader, |acc, f| Box::new(acc.chain(f)) as Box<dyn Read>);

    Ok(BufReader::new(stream).lines().filter_map(|line| {
        line.ok().and_then(|tag| {
            if let Ok(_tag) = tag.parse::<usize>() {
                Some(tag)
            } else {
                None
            }
        })
    }))
}
```

Note that using a `Box<dyn Read>` incurs some runtime overhead, as it leads to dynamic dispatch.